# How do I initialise generated mark-up?

Tags: vue.js

I want to add some more elements that react to a click handler at run-time (i.e. after the Vue instance has already been initialised). Adding to the DOM via `v-html` ultimately works, but the new `v-on` attributes remain unprocessed, thus these buttons are not functioning.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <title />
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
        <script><![CDATA[
$(async () => {
    new Vue({
        data: { x: null },
        el: '#v',
        methods: {
            even_number: function() {
                console.log('yep, it worked');
            },
            start: function() {
                let x = '';
                let i = 0;
                while (i < 20) {
                    let num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
                    if (num % 2) {
                        x += num + ' ';
                    } else {
                        x += `<button type="button" v-on="{click: even_number}">${ num }</button>` + ' ';
                    }
                    i++;
                }
                this.x = x;
            }
        }
    });
});
        ]]></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <dialog open="open" id="v">
            <button type="button" v-on="{click: start}">get this started</button>
            <pre><code v-html="x" /></pre>
        </dialog>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The easiest way would be to use your while loop to fill an array of data you want to display and do the rest in the template. Here is an idea: https://jsfiddle.net/3q0k8may/1/ but maybe your problem is more complex than your example.

Answer (score 0):

Using `v-html` limits you to raw html. Vue directives will not be handled as you're hoping.  From the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML):

> Note that you cannot use v-html to compose template partials, because Vue is not a string-based templating engine. Instead, components are preferred as the fundamental unit for UI reuse and composition.

Perhaps you could put some of the logic of `start` into the template and build a button that will render conditionally. See https://jsfiddle.net/ebbishop/f59ky7gj/ for an example.